# gradle - attach source jar file to depenency

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, ivy

I have a project with both maven depedencies and a dependency on an company-internal jar file stored in our company's ivy repository. It was published with an ivy ant task. Let's call this file myco.jar. there is a source file called myco-sources.jar, and it is in the same location as myco.jar.

When I build with gradle, via Eclipse, the maven dependencies automatically download the source jar file and attach it to the main jar in the generated .classpath file.  But for myco.jar, it does not automatically attach myco-sources.jar to it.  Instead, myco-sources.jar is downloaded as if it was a separate dependency.  So even though the source code is technically part of the classpath, I still can't step through the source code when debugging!

Here's a snippet of my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
   implementation "com.myco:modname:${versionNo}"
   implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:${jacksonVersion}"
...
}
```

How do I 'tell' gradle that the sources file is not a separate dependency but is the source file for the myco.jar file?

This is how the ivy.xml file looks like that is used to publish the myco.jar and myco-sources.jar files:

```
<publications>
  <artifact name="myco" type="jar" ext="jar"/>
  <artifact name="myco" e:classifier="sources" type="source" ext="jar"/>
```

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency ... />
  ...
</dependencies>
```

and this is the ant task CI runs to publish to our artifactory repository:

```
<target name="publish-task" depends="xxx" description="xxx">
   <ivy:resolve file="ivy.xml"/>
   <ivy:publish pubrevision="${version}" status="integration" resolver="xxx" overwrite="true">
      <artifacts pattern="${path}/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>
   </ivy:publish>
   <delete file="ivy-${version}.xml"/>
</target>
```

Comment: How is your ivy repository configured?

Comment: I've updated my original post to include ivy config info.